# Loop Audio in Javascript Until Alert Dismissed

Tags: javascript, audio

I've been doing some research and haven't found anything helpful to explain/lead me in the right direction. This is what I have so far. It works but the alert only plays for the preset time. I want it to play until the "Ok" button on the alert is clicked. Thanks

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function(){   
var old_count=<?php echo $arr['counter'];?>;
var audio=document.getElementById('audiotag1');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "dbcheck.php",
        timeout: 4000,
  
        success : function(data){
            if (data > old_count) {
                alert('New Hot Part Has Been Entered.');
  document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
  old_count=data;
    
  window.setTimeout(function(){ 
         location.reload();
  }, 10000);
            }

        }
    });
 
},5000);

</script>

<audio id="audiotag1" src="alert.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: Javascript stops executing while the alert is being displayed. It's not multithreaded.

Comment: If it happens to loop, but stops looping when the `alert()` shows up. That's because an alert stops execution of JavaScript until an action is taken. You can get around that by using simulated alert via libraries, for example [jqueryUI's alert boxes](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: This would be the most annoying thing _ever_, if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite easy to implement when you use a flag for audio looping and listen to the `ended` event of the `audio` element.

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    if(loopAudio){
        audio.play();
    }
});
...
// where you trigger the alert.
loopAudio = true;
audio.play();        
alert('click ok to stop audio looping.');
loopAudio = false;
audio.pause(); // if you want
...
```

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o7pwnbse/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a static version (html) of your problem. If you set the loop parameter of the audio to true. The audio does not stop even when an alert box opens up. I have pasted my code below. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Audio Loop</title>
</head>

<body onload="onload()">
<input type="text" value="1"> </input>
<audio id="audiotag1" src="alert.wav" preload="auto" ></audio>
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="stopAudio()"></input>
</body>
<script>


function onload(){
var old_count=document.getElementById('counter');
var audio=document.getElementById('audiotag1');
audio.loop=true;
audio.load();
audio.play()
}
function stopAudio(){
alert("Before Pause");
var audio=document.getElementById('audiotag1');
audio.pause();
}
</script></html>
```